# Is it ok to return IEnumerator<T>.GetEnumerator() in IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Basically suppose you have some collection:

```
public class FurCollection : IEnumerable<FurStrand>
{
   public IEnumerator<FurStrand> GetEnumerator()
   {
      foreach(var strand in this.Strands)
      {
         yield return strand;
      }
   }

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
      return this.GetEnumerator();
   }
}
```

Is this acceptable? Or is this bug-prone or bad practice? I will pretty much always be using the `IEnumerator<T`> but I still want the non-generic version to be stable and properly implemented.

Comment: I'm sure you mean **IEnumerable<FurStrands>** rather then **IEnumerator<FurStrands>** ...

Comment: Thanks sorry I wrote this sample quickly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is completely standard and recommended to comply with DRY and other concerns.

Note that

```
return strand;
```

should be

```
yield return strand;
```

Additionally, it looks like `this.Strands` already implements `IEnumerable<FurStrand>` so you could just say

```
return this.Strands.GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: Thanks man, sorry I just made this sample up, so forgot the yield.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is perfectly acceptable. Recommended even.

Answer (score 4):

Not only is this good practice, but your project will not complile without it, because `IEnumerable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable`. Look at the definition of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

You have to implement the non-generic version or you'll get an error "... does not implement interface member..."

Comment: You misunderstood the question.

Comment: Nevermind I get it. I think I learned to do it that way with generics, never occurred to me to NOT return the same enumerator.